# How to have multiple fibers in C++ -- like a vector of fibers

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I want to have multiple fibers running like so.

```
#include <boost/fiber/fiber.hpp>    

#include <vector>

void printNum(int i) {
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void handleInts (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>& ints) {
  std::vector<boost::fibers::fiber> runningFibers;
  for (auto& integer : ints) {
     runningFibers.emplace_back(boost::fibers::fiber([&](){ printNum(*integer);));
  }
}

int main() {
   
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> ints;
  
  auto firstInt = std::make_unique<int>(1);
  auto secondInt = std::make_unique<int>(2);

  ints.emplace_back(std::move(firstInt));
  ints.emplace_back(std::move(secondInt));

  handleInts(ints);
  
  return 0;
}
```

However this causes some kind of memory leak when I run with valgrind. How do I do what I am trying to do here but without memory leaks. I looked at boost's documentation but got confused.

Comment: Memory leaks are properties of complete programs, not fragments.  Can you post the complete program?  Ideally don't put the code in `main` as there are quirky static lifetime rules to stuff in main that I don't think are the core of your problem.

Comment: Okay so I edited it to give more context. In reality I am not using integers I am using protocol buffers but that is not as central to the question in my mind. I could mock one up if that is needed though.

Comment: So long as your example demonstrates the leak, that is the key part, so others can take your code and confirm it without having to invent code that may or may not fix your problem.  :)

Comment: Boost Context (a dependency) has a documented problem with valgrind that requires the library to be rebuilt with an option called "valgrind=on": https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/stack/valgrind.html . Is that a possible source of your errors?

Comment: Ohhhhh yeah that actually might be. I will try and figure out if I can do that.